# Is it possible to use CKAN for commercial use?

Tags: licensing, ckan

Does anyone know if it's possible to use CKAN for commercial use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

CKAN is licensed under Affero GNU GPL v3.0. From the preamble to the license:
When we speak of free software, we are referring to freedom, not price. Our General Public Licenses are designed to make sure that **you have the freedom to distribute copies of free software (and charge for them if you wish)**, that you receive source code or can get it if you want it, that you can change the software or use pieces of it in new free programs, and that you know you can do these things.

Sources: http://ckan.org/developers/about-ckan/, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLCommercially